# Error encountered when using the field_value_factor function in elasticsearch query

Tags: elasticsearch

everyone, I am using elasticsearch version 1.1.1, and I have verified the version correctly. In the elasticsearch documentation, there is a function score query which provides a function called field_value_factor, but when I try to use it, I get this error:

```
nested: QueryParsingException[[teindex] No function with the name [field_value_factor] is registered.]
```

Here is how I am using it:

```
           "function_score": {
              "functions": [
                 {
                    "gauss": {
                       "createVendor": {
                          "scale": "2d",
                          "offset": "5d",
                          "decay" : 0.5
                       }
                    }
                 },
                 {
                     "field_value_factor": {
                         "field" : "ipscore",
                         "modifier" : "log"
                     }
                 }
              ],
              "query": {
                 "multi_match": {
                    "query": "beach",
                    "fields": ["title^12","description^5","tags^8" ]
                 }
              },
              "score_mode": "multiply"
           }
```

Any clues as to why it is failing? Thanks.

Comment: I think that `field_value_factor` shouldn't be in `functions`

Comment: Are you sure this feature is in ES 1.1.1? I know it is mentioned in the docs, but it is marked as feature for [v1.2.0 on GitHub](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/pull/5519).

Comment: yes that's what I suspect, rare case whereby documentation keeps up faster than code, but it maybe true

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been having the same problem. As was suggested by @Thorsten, I can confirm this is definitely not available in v1.1.1 (which at time of writing is the latest version in the official repositories). It looks to me like it will be in v1.2.0... hopefully.

You can try something like this for now:

```
       "function_score": {
          "functions": [
             {
                "gauss": {
                   "createVendor": {
                      "scale": "2d",
                      "offset": "5d",
                      "decay" : 0.5
                   }
                }
             },
             {
                 "script_score": {
                "script": "_score * log(doc['ipscore'].value)"
            }
             }
          ],
          "query": {
             "multi_match": {
                "query": "beach",
                "fields": ["title^12","description^5","tags^8" ]
             }
          },
          "score_mode": "multiply"
       }
```

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what I did. Thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 0):

Field value factor seems to be available since Elasticsearch version 1.2.0, which has been released on May 22, 2014:

https://www.elastic.co/blog/elasticsearch-1-2-0-released

So upgrading to that version or a higher version should fix the issue.